# Isomorphic 2-graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism, directed-graphs

[Two graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkggI.png)

Can we say that these two graphs are isomorphic? I think no because $\deg^-(c) \ne \deg^-(g)$. The solution says they are isomorphic, but I don't understand why. Am I wrong?

Comment: "They say [the graphs] are isomorphic" - wait, but who is "they"? Anyway, the undirected versions of these graphs are isomorphic, but not the directed versions.

Comment: @runway44 The solution says it is isomorphics. Can you explain why? What kind of isomorphism is that?

Comment: What solution? In a textbook? In some class lecture? You aren't saying. Surely whatever source you're reading defined isomorphism before giving you a problem on isomorphisms. Undirected graph isomorphisms are a one-to-one correspondence between vertices that also creates a one-to-one correspondence between edges. For directed graphs, such a correspondence needs to preserve the orientation of edges.

Comment: Why did you change the graphs in your prompt? If you have questions on another problem with different graphs, you should either expand this post or open a new one, but not rewrite this one. Also, you should leave in your initial ideas to solve the problem, not delete them.

Comment: Please don't change your question to a completely different question. If you do that, then the answer I wrote for your original question makes no sense, and I worked hard writing that answer :(

Answer (score 4):

Both you and the solution are wrong.

Just saying that $\deg^-(c) \ne \deg^-(g)$ doesn't mean anything, because $c$ doesn't have to be paired with $g$. An isomorphism of these two directed graphs would be a function $$\phi : \{a, b, c, d\} \to \{e, f, g, h\}$$ that preserves directed edges. Checking that $\deg^-(c) \ne \deg^-(g)$ tells you that we cannot have $\phi(c) = g$ in any isomorphism. However, we have $\deg^-(c) = \deg^-(f)$, so we can't immediately rule out that there's an isomorphism $\phi$ with $\phi(c) = f$.

What we can say by looking at indegrees and outdegrees is that any isomorphism must have:

- $\phi(a) = h$, because these are the only vertices with outdegree $2$ and indegree $0$;
- $\phi(b) = g$, because these are the only vertices with outdegree $0$ and indegree $2$;
- either $\phi(c) = e$ and $\phi(d) = f$, or $\phi(c) = f$ and $\phi(d) = e$.

Possibly the solution telling you that the graphs are isomorphic made the mistake of only checking the degrees.

However, once we've figured out the above, we immediately know that there can't be an isomorphism, because there is an edge $(h,g)$ but no edge $(a,b)$.